# Wordpress remove active border

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the active border on the search form up top on this site: http://teenhealth.s467.sureserver.com/ .  I believe this is a default setting and can't figure out how/where to remove it.  Any help would be super appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `style.css` file at line 32, include this:

```css
input#s:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

If you want to ensure that you don't get this same blue glow on any of your other form inputs, you could instead put this somewhere near the top of your CSS file:

```css
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

This will remove the outline from all form elements when focused.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Do feel free to open up another question if you need any further help.  Please remember to mark the correct answer when you're done with a question (there's a tick outline on the left side of each answer).  This will ensure that future visitors to the site are able to find the correct answer as quickly and easily as possible.